# chef-client override runlist does not update attributes on the server

Tags: chef-infra

I have a cookbook with attributes. I add a recipe from this cookbook to run list of a node. I run `chef-client` on that node and see the attributes and their values on the chef server.
Later I made changes to cookbook attributes, uploaded the cookbook, ran that specific recipe using `-o` option. I do not see the updated values of the attributes on the chef server.

I read somewhere that -o option does not update the chef server. So is it that we should not use -o option frequently and use it only for development purpose.

If the cookbook was always run through -o option can not see the attributes and the recipe on the node attribute on the server (which I think is bad?).

Thanks
Amod

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the sentiment that you're probably doing it wrong, if you need to override the runlist one way of achieving it is:

a)
create /etc/chef/alternative.json, with the content below filled with your alternative runlist:

> {"run_list":[]}

b) make sure you have the “real” runlist of the node in e.g. /etc/chef/first-boot.json

c) Periodically run the command below to refresh statistics

> chef-client -j /etc/chef/empty.json

d) when you really want to converge the node, use:

> chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json

Answer (score 0):

the `-o` option is there to allow a chef-run with a totally different runlist than usual, thus not saving it to chef-server.

If you need to run periodically with `-o`, you're probably doing it wrong.
Make your recipe idempotent or change it so it can be enabled for a run using a flag somewhere (node attribute or data-bag item) without modifying the node run list

Without the use case it's hard to give a correct advice on how to address this.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer. But I am looking for a detailed answer on why it does not work. From sever I have no clue if someone has run a recipe with -o (while it does affect the node it does not inform the server. sneaky?). I understand that -o does not save the data. But the question is, why it is designed like that. It is misleading to me so it could be a bad design. I am not trying to solve any particular use case. Thanks again.

Comment: Well the documentation of chef-client options is [here](http://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options). The idea behind -o is to run a specific recipe, maybe to fix chef-client conf before the full run or just to run the omnibus-updater recipe, or whatever would be a one time modification not handable in a full runlist run.

Comment: The entire point of `-o` is to allow a one-time override of the run list.  As such, the assumption is that you don't want to save the data.  Why not?, well you 'normally' run a bunch of recipes that all save data on the node.  If your 'one time' runlist were allowed to result in a `node.save` then all of your **normal** node data would be lost.  The purpose of `-o` is to give you a way to avoid that.  So that you can run one-off things (like a fix for bug) without corrupting your node data.